# push alarm message in android

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

I'm developing an Android app and I have a question.

I receive an alarm while developing a push alarm, but I want to customize the icon as shown in the image below. What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw5Oq.png)

my app....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIm0c.png)

my code...

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String body) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        // 알림을 클릭했을 때 앱으로 이동하기 위한 Intent 설정
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // 기존의 액티비티 스택을 모두 제거하고 새로운 액티비티를 생성
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE );

//        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.todaysun_logo_notification);
//        int newWidth = 100; // 조절할 새로운 이미지의 폭
//        int newHeight = 100; // 조절할 새로운 이미지의 높이
//        boolean filter = true; // 이미지를 부드럽게 할지 여부
//        Bitmap scaledLargeIcon = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(largeIcon, newWidth, newHeight, filter);
//
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.todaysun_logo);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.todaysun_notification2)
                .setContentTitle(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + title+ "</b>"))
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))  // 알림 메세지를  ... 아닌 전체 받을 수 있도록 처리
                .setColor(Color.BLUE)
//                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(largeIcon).bigLargeIcon(null))
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
                ;

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());


    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw5Oq.png)